# File Storage in clusters

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, openmp

I am working on a hybrid programming exercise using Open Mp and MPI, that has to be tested up on a cluster. The goal is basically to make an index of relevant words after processing a large set of files. What I am confused about is whether these files have to be sent to the respective nodes, from the root, or that they should already be there in the respective nodes. Thanks.

Comment: Either of those approaches will work.  And some might think that what you identify as alternatives are, from another point of view, aspects of the same approach.

Comment: Most clusters use shared file systems such as NFS or Lustre. In that case neither copying nor broadcasting of data is necessary.